# SharePoint Online document library column type doesn't match column type of it content type

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a SharePoint site with 200000+ document libraries. I have a custom context type "My library content type" and is used for all the document libraries.

At beginning, one of the columns DocumentID in the "My library content type" is number type. Later I changed it to string (single line of text). After SharePoint finished the update, I found out "DocumentID" on some of the libraries
are changed to string type, while some are still have number type. And also "DcoumentID" column on some libraries was changed to string type, but the relation to the custom content type is lost.

Any idea how to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

There may be something wrong in the backend. You can open a service request in Microsoft 365 admin center to let Microsoft help you check this issue form the backend.